# Disabling and enabling a textbox depending on if a div is visible or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a calendar tool which is giving some problem on the android browser. I am writing a custom JS to make it work on the same. Here's the working- If you click on the text box, a calender pops up and the text box gets disabled. If you click anywhere else, the calender hides.
Here the hidden div for the calender

I want to enable/disable the text box depending on whether the calender has display: none; or display: block;

Comment: `.attr("disabled", ???)` at the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

didn't tested, can you try this?

```
 if($('#calendar').css('display') == 'block'){ //if calendar has css display:block; rule

    $('#textbox').attr('disabled','disabled'); //disable textbox
    }

 if(!$('#calendar').is('visible')){  //if calendar is hidden , so has css display:none;

    $('#textbox').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable textbox

    }
```